# React & Material UI - How to Remove Nav Buttons/Links based on Routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The code below is the main app.js entry of a React app and it includes the routers endpoints.

Below the app.js code is the code of a Nav (navigation) component. I want to know how to structure this code so that when a user goes to a specific route the respective link in the Nav is removed.
In other words if the user is at localhost:3000/calendar  the tab with the word "calendar" should not appear in the Nav component.

I could parse the endpoints and do this with a bunch of ugly conditionals that render different Nav code based on the parsed endpoints  - but I figure there is a simpler way that I don't see to do what I want.

Thanks.

**App.js**

```
function App(){

    ...code

    function redirectToClientsList(){
        window.location.href = "/";
    }


    function redirectToCalendar(){
        window.location.href = "/calendar";
    }




    return (
       <div className="App">
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>

                    <Nav redirectToClientsList = {redirectToClientsList} redirectToCalendar={redirectToCalendar} />

                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <div>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Landing} />
                                <Route exact={true} path="/test" component={Test} />
                                <Route exact={true} path="/client/:id/client-name/:client/workflows" component={Workflows} />
                                <Route exact={true} path="/calendar" component={Calendar} />
                                <Redirect from="/*" to="/" />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

**Nav component.**

```
function Navbar(props){

    const {classes} = props;

    return (


          <AppBar className={classes.bgColor} >


            <Toolbar>

                  <Button color="inherit" onClick ={props.redirectToClientsList}>Clients</Button> 
                  <Button color="inherit" onClick ={props.redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button>
                  <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} style={{float:"right"}} color="inherit">SAVE</Button>


            </Toolbar>

          </AppBar>



    )
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const styles = theme => (navbarStyle(theme));
export default withStyles(styles)(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `withRouter` provided by the `react-router-4` package.

**Here's an example using the `withRouter`**

---

You can get access to the `history` object’s properties and the closest `<Route>`'s match via the `withRouter` *higher-order* component. `withRouter` will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` *props* to the *wrapped component* whenever it renders.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location

class ShowTheLocation extends Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" to the router  
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

**After getting access to the `current location` *aka* `route` object you can do a simple `if check` to determine which buttons should be displayed on that particular `route`. I would create a helper function that should determine just that, put it inside of the `componentDidMount` lifecycle or the equivalent `useEffect` hook (if you choose that approach)`, save the result to the state and finally do an if check and depending on its results, show/ hide buttons**

---

**Important Note:**
`withRouter` does not subscribe to `location` changes like *`React-Redux`’s* `connect` does for state changes. Instead, re-renders after location changes propagate out from the `<Router>` component. This means that withRouter does not re-render on route transitions *unless its parent component re-renders.*

---

**You could wrap your app.js component with the `withRouter` HOC and get the necessary props in your `Nav.js` component**

```
// ....
<div className="App">
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                      <Nav redirectToClientsList = {redirectToClientsList} redirectToCalendar={redirectToCalendar} />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                            <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
                            <Route exact path="/client/:id/client-name/:client/workflows" component={Workflows} />
                            <Route exact path="/calendar" component={Calendar} />
                            <Redirect from="/*" to="/" />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </div>

// LET'S NOW WRAP OUR App.js COMPONENT WITH THE withRouter HOC - [don't forget to import it first] :)
export default withRouter(App);
```

---

**Nav.js**

```
function Navbar(props){

    const {classes} = props;

      // We're interested in the current path,
     // so, we'll destructure it from the location property    
    const { pathname } = props.location;

    return ( 
          <AppBar className={classes.bgColor} >
            <Toolbar>

             // Here we're going to do our check
             {pathname !== "calendar" ?
                  <Button color="inherit" onClick ={props.redirectToCalendar}>Calendar</Button> : null}

                   <Button color="inherit" onClick ={props.redirectToClientsList}>Clients</Button> 

                  <Button className={classes.saveDataButton} style={{float:"right"}} color="inherit">SAVE</Button>

            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
```

Comment: I have wrapped the App component in withRouter() and exported it. Now, when I am in the Nav and I try to console props.location it comes back as undefined. When I console.log props no new props appear albeit wrapping app in withRouter does not throw an error so something is right so far. I am using react-router 4.3.1

Comment: @William Try putting your `<Nav>` component inside of the `BrowserRouter`

Comment: I still get the same problem. I am going to create a new create-react-app instance and do a spike test to see if I can get it working outside my app. I'll then take it from there. If you have any more insight feel free. Thanks so far!

Comment: I see the prob. The location prop (and other props Match,History) are only available in the App component and I need to pass it to the Nav component. In other words, the props from App do not pass automatically to the child component (Nav).

Comment: It works. You might want to add curly braces around the part of your code that is in parens where it starts with the word pathname and ends at null. :)

Comment: @William I wrote that code on the fly. I'm glad it worked out for you. Regarding `location` not being present or essentially being `undefined`: **If you wrap the parent component with `withRouter` all child components will have access to the `match`, `history`, and `location` properties** or you could wrap the component that actually needs it with `withRouter` HOC and then get access to the mention properties via props.